# Can't merge user_target_xcconfig for pod targets: ["Reanimated", "hermes-engine"]. Singular build setting CLANG_CXX_LIBRARY has different values

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, react-native

I've been running "pod install" in my project to connect my dependencies but I've been getting this error: `Can't merge user_target_xcconfig for pod targets: ["Reanimated", "hermes-engine"] Singular build setting CLANG_CXX_LIBRARY has different values.` everytime I run pod. I tried to work around this error, I've deleted and reinstalled all pod files as well but no luck.

Wondering if anyone found a solution for this ?

Comment: Have you found a solution to this?

Comment: @RaideR Not yet, but for now  I migrated all the necessary folders and files expected for package.json to a new project folder and ran ‘pod install’ before installing the dependencies. Installed all the dependencies again ran ‘expo-doctor’ and ran ‘pod install‘ after all the dependencies were installed.

Comment: any update on this?

Comment: There is no resolution yet. Hermes specifies one language standard (https://github.com/facebook/hermes/blob/181475922b6190d6e2fcded6a3116549f5eadee8/hermes-engine.podspec#L36 - "c++17"), reanimated specifies another (https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-reanimated/blob/acf7429068c4f801eef41267c2a94b5515ec4ff8/ios/RNReanimated.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj#L403 - "gnu++0x), in current versions. Until they reconcile I'm not sure what you can do.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**Happy update!** [reanimated 2.10.0 is released now](https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-reanimated/releases/tag/2.10.0), and it appears to have the required patch according to a timely comment from @Lauri-Harpf - 2.10.0 also contains pre-built libs (as required by reanimated 2.x) for react-native 0.70.x so this answer is largely obsolete, but in a good way. Go grab the new release and give a star to the repo + support Software Mansion if you can, as they do a great job on the module. Cheers

Mostly obsolete answer follows:

---

### react-native 0.69

It appears the answer is to update react-native-reanimated in order for it to be more compatible with react-native 0.69

There is not an official release with it for react-native 0.69 (for react-native 0.70 see below), but patch-package may be used to integrate a fix as described here:

https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-reanimated/issues/3326#issuecomment-1225057452

(basically, you forcefully alter the C++ language standard reanimated uses by altering it's podspec file to be the one Hermes wants, using patch-package to do the whole thing cleanly.

```
diff --git a/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/RNReanimated.podspec b/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/RNReanimated.podspec
index d53cb12..719f813 100644
--- a/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/RNReanimated.podspec
+++ b/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/RNReanimated.podspec
@@ -94,7 +94,7 @@ Pod::Spec.new do |s|
   }
   s.compiler_flags = folly_compiler_flags + ' ' + boost_compiler_flags
   s.xcconfig               = {
-    "CLANG_CXX_LANGUAGE_STANDARD" => "c++14",
+    "CLANG_CXX_LANGUAGE_STANDARD" => "c++17",
     "HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS" => "\"$(PODS_ROOT)/boost\" \"$(PODS_ROOT)/boost-for-react-native\" \"$(PODS_ROOT)/glog\" \"$(PODS_ROOT)/#{folly_prefix}Folly\" \"${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/React-hermes\" \"${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/hermes-engine\"",
                                "OTHER_CFLAGS" => "$(inherited)" + " " + folly_flags  }
```

### react-native 0.70

For react-native 0.70, you need to use the 3.x versions of react-native-reanimated, which do not have an official release as of this writing.

You do that by installing the `react-native-reanimated@next` version, for example as `yarn add react-native-reanimated@next`, then `pod install` and the error should be gone.

Comment: Really good point conerning react-native 0.70 

Comment: Great answer, thanks! React-native-reanimated 2.10.0 that has been patched as suggested seems to also work with React Native 0.70.1 though. Do you know of any critical issues why react-native-reanimated 2.10.0 wouldn't work with RN >0.70?

Comment: Hmm - looking at the release notes for 2.10.0, they state clearly that they added support for rn 0.70 so I will take them at their word (in my opinion, software mansion is a great shop that does their best for good maintenance - it is worth taking them at their word). reanimated 3.x shifts to "compile during build" while 2.x requires pre-built libs for each supported, so until they added support directly in a release it was just a hard no. Thanks for the heads up, I will edit

Comment: I found I had to use rehan-shakir's answer with RN 0.70.1 even with react-native-reanimated 2.10.0.

Comment: Really after updates from RN, have to pray so project works smoothly. Really frustrating.

Comment: @ChiragPurohit you are not wrong, but see what it sounds like if you "expand" the idea of react-native to it's first level dependencies - "Really after updates to Android, iOS, Xcode, macOS, Node, the JDK, Gradle, App Store and Play Store policies, you have to p ray your project works smoothly". The sheer amount of technology bundled in one thing called "react-native" is mind-blowing, and as a combinatorial problem it's amazing it works. That said, they're focusing on the upgrade process for the next few releases, hopefully it helps.

Comment: Is there a fix for expo projects?

Comment: i have a dirrefent one: [!] Can't merge pod_target_xcconfig for pod targets: ["expo-dev-menu", "Main", "SafeAreaView", "Vendored"]. Singular build setting DEFINES_MODULE has different values., can you help me please?

Answer (score 8):

Simple Answer is
Just set the CXX n the podspec.

```
node_modules/react-native-reanimated/RNReanimated.podspec
```

Change to:

```
"CLANG_CXX_LANGUAGE_STANDARD" => "c++17",
```

***Credits*** => **https://github.com/Shopify/react-native-skia/issues/405#issuecomment-1244302303**

Comment: I found I had to use this even with react-native-reanimated 2.10.0. Then use patch-package to persist the change.

Comment: Same here. 2.10.0 and still getting that problem. Using RN 0.70.3.

Answer (score 4):

Fixed for expo eas build on SDK 46 by updating to reanimated `2.12.0`

Still throws error regarding CLANG_LANGUAGE_STANDARD and CLANG_LIBRARY for ["Reanimated" , "hermes-engine"] but not anymore for ["RNReanimated", "Reanimated", "hermes-engine"].

The build was crashing on startup in testflight, but does not do that anymore.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, in case you use Expo with expo-dev-client, expo-dev-menu pulls in a bundled react-native-reanimated. This is where the error is coming from in my case. [It should be fixed](https://github.com/expo/expo/pull/20332), but at least a fresh Expo project I created yesterday still sports the issue, so the fix must not be released yet. The warning/error is gone after patching the podspec.

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to update to reanimated to v3.0.0-rc.3

Answer (score 0):

I came across this error by installing:

- react-native: 0.70.2
- react-navigation v6
- react-native-reanimated 2.10.0
- "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.5.0",
- "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.13",
- "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.0",

React-Navigation does not mention any support yet for Animate V3 or Animate (next).

And as far as I heard, there is some major change on how Animate works behind the curtons (v2 and v3)

So I changed like mentioned in the post above the c++ version, made with patch-package a patch, and build the react native apps for android and iOS like mentioned on the react-native docs.
And I can confirm everything worked just fine.

I didn't know at this point in time how patch-package worked, here some video in case you might also be new to this:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2AVs-Yh1bS8&t=3s&ab_channel=BenAwad

Answer (score 0):

Basically, make sure your version of react-native-animated is congruent with the version of react-native you're using.

RNAnimated => 2.17.0 works with RN => 0.71.6